# MySQL server on Azure portal db cannot use default (current_date)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, azure, azure-mysql-database

When running

```
 creation_date date default (current_date),
```

getting error on MySQL server on Azure portal, but not on local MySQL workbench. How can we give the current date as default?

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can get current time by following sql querys:

```
  SELECT SYSDATETIME()
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/9lp2Z6F.png]

```
Select  SYSDATETIMEOFFSET ()
```

[image]

If you want to change to time zone you are living you can change it to local also, for further reference to change to local time refer this [site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-query-to-convert-utc-to-local-time-zone/#:%7E:text=SELECT%20CONVERT%28datetime,%20SWITCHOFFSET%28,gets%20converted%20to%20local%20IST.).